# phpliteadmin says SQLite3: not installed but it is

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to install phpliteadmin on a raspberry.
I installed sqlite3, apache and php

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 -y
sudo apt-get install apache2 -y
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php -y
```

when i know try to start phpliteadmin in an empty directory and try to create a database i get the following error:

```
PDO: installed
PDO SQLite Driver: not installed
SQLite3: not installed
SQLiteDatabase: not installed
```

when i install the pdo sqlite driver the errot goes away but i want to use the other databse php extensions, because with the PDO SQLite Driver i cannot read database with WAL set.
why do i get the error SQLite3: not installed when it is installed. is there anything missing?

Comment: You have to install the relevant language specific bindings for sqlite if they're not included in that languages base install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the sqlite-extension of PHP. I guess on Raspbian, it should be:

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

More details can be found in the phpLiteAdmin wiki: https://bitbucket.org/phpliteadmin/public/wiki/Installation