# When I try to create a new db on phpliteadmin. It says "PDO: installed PDO SQLite Driver: installed SQLite3: installed SQLiteDatabase: not installed"

Tags: php, database, windows, sqlite

This is what I've got

```
PDO: installed
PDO SQLite Driver: installed
SQLite3: installed
SQLiteDatabase: not installed
```

I need a solution for this plz help.Once SQLite3 not installed error got, but I change php.ini file then it solved. but this didn't.

Comment: @nbk the question is about [phpliteadmin](https://www.phpliteadmin.org/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [phpliteadmin says SQLite3: not installed but it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239548/phpliteadmin-says-sqlite3-not-installed-but-it-is)